# Spring data query with nested fields (joining other columns)

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I've got 3 entities
`Topic`, `Text` and `Author`.

`Topic 1:n Text and Text 1:n Author`

My entites looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class Topic {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private LocalDate date;
    private String name;
    @JoinColumn(name = "text_id", nullable = false)
    private Text text;
}

@Entity
public class Text {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private LocalDate date;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    @JoinColumn(name = "author_id", nullable = false)
    private Author author;
}

public class Author{
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
}
```

now I try to create spring data jpa query to get topics between dates for specific authors.

Solution for just dates between works:

```
List<Topic> findByDateBetween(LocalDate begin, LocalDate end);
```

I tried things like:

```
List<Topic> findByDateBetween_AuthorId(LocalDate begin, LocalDate end, int authorId);
List<Topic> findByDateBetweenAuthorId(LocalDate begin, LocalDate end, int authorId);
List<Topic> findByDateBetweenAuthor_id(LocalDate begin, LocalDate end, int authorId);
```

Nothing worked. Any Suggestions?

Comment: have you tried `findByDateBetweenTextAuthorId` ?

Comment: Try this `List<Topic> findByDateBetweenAndAuthorId(LocalDate begin, LocalDate end, int authorId);`

Comment: I have no way to check that now, but I would try reversing the arguments, something like `findByAuthorIdAndDateBetween`.

Comment: Also try this findByDateBetweenAndTextAuthorId(LocalDate begin, LocalDate end, int authorId);

Comment: Yeah the problem can be with position of arguments, give me second to check that.

Comment: Suggestion of @KamilW. with adding keyword "and" helped out. :) Thanks all of you.

Comment: Glad to hear it :)

Answer (score 1):

In JPA repository of Topic you can write custom query.

```
@Query("SELECT t FROM Topic t" +
       "JOIN t.text tx " + 
       "JOIN tx.author a " + 
       "WHERE a.id = :authorId AND t.date >= :begin AND t.date <= :end")
List<Topic> getTopicsInDatesByAuthor(@Param("begin") LocalDate begin, @Param("end") LocalDate end, @Param("authorId") int authorId);
```